# How to access a value in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary called 'myjson' that contains a list of dictionaries, indexed by the column names of a tab-delimited spreadsheet.  Each row of the spreadsheet is a dictionary, with the keys corresponding to the columns of the spreadsheet and the values corresponding to the entries in the particular row.

Simplified ex:

```
{'name':'Sam', 'DoB': 5/23/2000'}
{'name':'Jon', 'DoB': 5/10/2000'}
```

I need to access the name "column" or "set of values" (not sure how to refer to them)?

How do I do this?
Had a lot of trouble, trying

`myjson[0].itervalues()` gives me all the values

but `myjson[0][name]` doesn't work...

---

ADDING TO THIS:

I'm trying to parse a string containing a name and a degree. I have a long list of these. Some contain no degrees, some contain one, and some contain multiple.

Ex strings:

```
Sam da Man J.D.
Green Eggs Jr. Ed.M.
Argle Bargle Sr. MA
Cersei Lannister M.A. Ph.D.
```

As far as I can tell, the degrees come in the following patterns:

```
x.x.
x.x.x.
x.x.xx.
x.xx.
xx.x.
x.xxx.
two caps (ex: 'MA')
```

How would I parse this? I have been reading regex and think that .match() might be the way to go, but I don't understand how to have a list of patterns to match.

Thanks!

Comment: you should ask a new question

Comment: if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412017/how-to-access-a-value-in-a-list-of-dictionaries) question is done, you may accept one by click right. If you wants

Answer (score 3):

You have supplied the dictionary with a key of the string `'name'`, so that is what you need to use to access it.  `myjson[0]['name']` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `'name'` not `name`, because without quotes python would think you're referring to some variable `name`.

Use a list comprehension to get all such values:

```
>>> lis = [{'name':'Sam', 'DoB': '5/23/2000'},{'name':'Jon', 'DoB': '5/10/2000'}]
>>> [x['name'] for x in lis]
['Sam', 'Jon']
```

Comment: OP's one confusion is why `myjson[0].itervalues()` and `myjson[0][name]` are same, read last line.  (point yet not answered)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No they're not same, after reading OP's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412017/how-to-access-a-value-in-a-list-of-dictionaries/17412059?noredirect=1#comment25285529_17412047) I think quotation marks was the issue.